# Is that possible to do Typescript generic interface with Gatsby Typegen Queries?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to do a generic interface like this working with Gatsby GraphQL Typegen :

```js
interface CarouselInterface<TypeQuery> {
    data: TypeQuery, // Value that would go there : Queries.Type1Fragment | Queries.Type2Fragment
    type: string
}
```

Documentation of Gatsby GraphQL Typegen: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/graphql-typegen/

That I can call in a function like this :

```js
export default function Carousel<TypeQuery>(props: CarouselInterface<TypeQuery>) {

    if (props.type === "type1") {
        return (          
            data.nodesType1.map((node) => ( // Error : Property 'nodesType1' does not exist on type 'TypeQuery'.
                <Type1 node={node} key={node.id} />
            ))
        )
    } else if (props.type === "type2") {
        return (
            data.nodesType2?.map((node) => ( // Error : Property 'nodesType2' does not exist on type 'TypeQuery'.
                <Type2 node={node} key={node.id} />
            )) 
        )
    }

    return null;
}
```

The goal is to use a Carousel for multiples elements in the website (with multiples GraphQL queries / datas). But I can't find the good way to do that… Thank you!